# Refresh more than one picture in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

In my program appear two pictures at once and I want that by press by a button, both are changing. Well first I had only one and that worked great. but now, I added a second one and realized that now only the second is being refreshed. Here is my code:

```
def next_picture():
# first picture
global nr
nr = nr + 1
print(nr)
img = Image.open(richtige_Bilder[nr]).resize((großes_Bild))
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
panel.config(image=img)  # update existing label
panel.image = img
panel.place(x=position_x, y=position_y)

# second picture
img2 = Image.open(richtige_Bilder[nr])
img2 = img2.resize((großes_bild_unten), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
panel.config(image=img2)
panel.image = img2
panel.place(x=großes_bild_unten_x, y=großes_Bild_unten_y)

schaltf1 = tk.Button(root, text="next", command=next_picture)
schaltf1.pack(side=RIGHT)
```

I think it's because both are in the same function and somehow python only refreshes the last `panel.config`. Maybe someone has a solution. How can I put both in the same function, because it would make everything way easier? If it's possible, maybe I could also put multiple commands in a button (inside more than one function) but I don't know how (don't prefer this one...)

```
img = Image.open(richtige_Bilder[nr])
img = img.resize((großes_Bild), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
panel = Label(root, image=img)
panel.image = img
panel.place(x=position_x, y=position_y)
print(nr)
#Vorschau unten
img2 = Image.open(richtige_Bilder[nr])
img2 = img2.resize((großes_bild_unten), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
panel = Label(root, image=img2)
panel.image = img2
panel.place(x=großes_bild_unten_x, y=großes_Bild_unten_y)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. In python indentation changes the behavior of your program so it's difficult to understand what it is supposed to to if it's indented incorrectly

Comment: btw. i am not native english speaker so do you mean with indentaion the open spaces between the lines of code? Well if so, I changed everything how my IDE likes it and its still dont work..

Comment: You used same `panel` for the two images.  You should use another one for the second image.

Comment: how do I do it? @acw1668. and thanks for the last time :D

Comment: How do you show the two images initially?

Comment: @acw1668 I added the code for the beginning

Comment: You should use different names for the two labels, for example `panel1` and `panel2`.

Comment: yes it works! Thanks again :D @acw1668. you are awesome